# UI operations from TcpClient DataReadAsyncCallback

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, tcpclient

Is TcpClient DataReadAsyncCallback executes in the main UI thread?
I'm creating windows forms from that handler and after several calls and window displays application just terminates without any exceptions from .NET.

```
...
ns.BeginRead(client.RxPacket, 0, client.RxPacket.Length, new AsyncCallback(TcpClientDataReadAsyncCallback), client);
...

private void TcpClientDataReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Client client = (Camera)ar.AsyncState;

    // read data 
    // create window form with that data recieved

    MyForm form = new MyForm(/*read data passed*/);
    form.Show(); 
}
```

Or should I use delegates to follow UI access from another thread?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is to check if invoke is required :

```
        MyForm form = new MyForm(/*read data passed*/);
        if (form.InvokeRequired)
            form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => form.Show()));
        else
            form.Show();
```

Comment: the InvokeRequired returns false, while debugging the code, immediately after Show() call debugger closes the application with no errors produced except in Output window InvalidOperationException in mscorlib.dll and ObjectDisposedException in system.dll

Comment: I believe the problem is how to create windows form from another thread